# How do I disable the Kernel SCTP on Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, sctp

I'm trying to automate my testing tool by making a Dockerfile and the tool requires me to disable the Kernel SCTP. The way I found that works for me when I was testing on VMs is add the lines

blacklist sctp

install sctp /bin/false

To: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

After that I have to reboot the machine which does not work or I don't know how to do on Docker.

```
...
RUN mkdir /etc/modprobe.d/ \
    && touch /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf \
    && echo "blacklist sctp" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf \
    && echo "install sctp /bin/false" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
...
```

My question is: How do I disable the Kernel SCTP without restarting or how do I restart the docker container?

Comment: With containers SCTP support is disabled by default,no need to do that.

Comment: @RichardRublev Yeah, I read something like that too, but it doesn't work. Here's the error I get:
```ERROR: Kernel SCTP seems to be available! You cannout use sctplib and kernel SCTP simultaneously!```